# How do I make a boxplot in ggplot2 that makes a box for each column in a dataframe/matrix?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Essentially, I want to make one plot that has 5 boxplots in it. Each box representing the Min/1stQ/Mean/3rdQ/Max of each column, specifically in the `ggplot2` library using `geom_boxplot()`.

My confusion lies in the fact that `geom_boxplot()` wants to take variables as `x` and `y` parameters, but that's not what I want to do.

I want the X-axis to represent the columns, and the Y-axis to represent the Min/1stQ/Mean/3rdQ/Max of each of them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You can provide your data via the output of `dput(df)` or to give a minimal subset use `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide any reproducible example, I assume that you have a data frame with five columns like this:

```
DF <- mtcars[,c(1,2,5,6,7)]
head(DF)
#                  mpg cyl drat    wt  qsec
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6 3.90 2.620 16.46
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 3.90 2.875 17.02
#Datsun 710        22.8   4 3.85 2.320 18.61
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 3.08 3.215 19.44
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 3.15 3.440 17.02
#Valiant           18.1   6 2.76 3.460 20.22
```

You want to make one plot that has 5 boxplots, each of which represents each column. It is likely that you want to get this.

```
boxplot(DF, xlab = "column_names", ylab = "column_values", las = 1)
grid()
```

[image]

However, you want to get a similar plot by using ggplot. If that's true, you need to transform `DF` so that all of the column names of `DF` are stored in a single column so that it can be assigned to `x`, which ggplot requires. Likewise, all the corresponding values should be stored in another column so that it can be assigned to `y`, which ggplot requires. You can do this transformation by using `pivot_longer`.

```
library(tidyverse)
newDF <- DF %>% 
         pivot_longer(col= everything(), 
                      values_to = "column_values", 
                      names_to = "column_names")

newDF
# A tibble: 160 x 2
#   column_names column_values
#   <chr>                <dbl>
# 1 mpg                  21   
# 2 cyl                   6   
# 3 drat                  3.9 
# 4 wt                    2.62
# 5 qsec                 16.5 
# 6 mpg                  21   
# 7 cyl                   6   
# 8 drat                  3.9 
# 9 wt                    2.88
#10 qsec                 17.0 
# ... with 150 more rows
```

It is now possible to plot 5 boxplots from `newDF`:

```
newDF %>% ggplot(aes(x = column_names, y = column_values)) +
 geom_boxplot(fill = "grey") + theme_bw()
```

Here is the resulted plot:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help. Apologies for my lackluster question, it was in a frantic "I don't know what to do" late night coding session, and I've never posted here before. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad if it helps. Next time, in case you want to post another question, it would be much better if you provide a reproducible example so that other users can understand quickly what you need. You can see the link in Andrew Gillreath-Brown's comment.

Comment: Also, please kindly accept my answer if you find it helpful to solve your problem.